# Overwriting Session Config To Add In 1 Week Of Keep Me Logged in Cookies Features

Tags: magento2, session, magento2.3.5, magento2.3.5-p2, customer-login

I am using Magento2.3.5-p2 installed on Ubuntu 20.04

I am required to implement a function in which at the login page when the user ticks on Remember Me checkbox, the system will store the cookies for that user, and that user will be kept logged in inside the system for 1 week

I am able to store the remember me detail cookies such as credential and remember_me_checkbox value by creating this file here and extends to the LoginPost class

`app/code/Vendor/Rememberme/Controller/Account/LoginPost.php`

extends to

`vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Account/LoginPost.php`

the cookies are stored correctly and securely as I implemented encryption when storing the cookies

So now I am required to make sure that the cookies are read well so that when the user log in they will stay logged in as per the requirement

so I add in this code file

`app/code/Vendor/Session/Controller/Config.php`

which extend to the class

`vendor/magento/framework/Session/Config.php`

The code are as below

```
<?php
/**
 * Session configuration object
 *
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Vendor\Session\Controller;

use Magento\Framework\App\DeploymentConfig;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
use Magento\Framework\Session\Config\ConfigInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\CookieManagerInterface;


class Config extends \Magento\Framework\Session\Config implements ConfigInterface
{
    protected $cookieManager;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\ValidatorFactory $validatorFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $stringHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request,
        Filesystem $filesystem,
        DeploymentConfig $deploymentConfig,
        $scopeType,
        $lifetimePath,
        CookieManagerInterface $cookieManager
        ) {

        $this->cookieManager = $cookieManager;
        $this->lifetimePath = 'web/cookie/cookie_lifetime';

        // changed
        // overwrite cookie lifetime with 1 week of remember me cookies
        if($this->cookieManager->getCookie('remember')){
            $remember_me_cookies = json_decode($this->cookieManager->getCookie('remember'));

            if($remember_me_cookies->remchkbox){
                $this->setCookieLifetime('604800', self::COOKIE_LIFETIME_DEFAULT);
            }
        }
        // end change

        return parent::__construct(
            $validatorFactory,
            $scopeConfig,
            $stringHelper,
            $request,
            $filesystem,
            $deploymentConfig,
            $scopeType,
            $lifetimePath
        );
    }
}
```

I am not sure where I have made the wrong changes because when I run bin/magento setup:di:compile && bin/magento setup:upgrade error as below appears

```
In AbstractFactory.php line 261:
                                                                                 
  Missing required argument $lifetimePath of Vendor\Session\Controller\Config.
```

do help provide solution to this problem, thank you

Comment: enable Persistence feature and Enable "Remember Me" feature

Comment: but the Remember me functionality featured in Magento 2 are not for the purpose for keeping the user logged in, it's for the use of the item in the cart to keep stay even when the user got logged out,

I have tried on fresh magento2 installation to verify the functionality magento2 provide on the remember me and it is really just for the purpose of the persistence shopping cart, nothing else

that is why I added this new remember me keep me logged in features

Comment: so I updated the codes by commenting the line of codes containing lifetimePath, no error during di compile and di upgrade, but during accessing the web page, error such as this appear "
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function create() on null in /var/www/project/vendor/magento/framework/Session/Config.php:315 Stack trace: #0"